# Meaning of " you run your ass off"

Tags: meaning

> You run your ass off.

Can *ass* be the object of *run*? Why isn't it just "you run"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> You run your ass off

implies that you are running so hard that your buttocks fall off. Obviously that never happens, but it is a figurative way of stating that you are doing something to the point of exhaustion and beyond. It is a familiar trope used with other pursuits as well:

> I worked my ass off on that project.
>
> We're going to party our asses off once we graduate.

And so on.